# Problems with simple form validation using html and css

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple form that needs to be validated and I have no idea why I cannot make a start. I looked at many examples online which are very similar and yet I cant  make it work

Here's the HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>A BSL Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./A BSL Quiz_files/bsl-QUIZ.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./A BSL Quiz_files/validate-QUIZ.js.download"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">

<h1>Sign Language</h1>


<div id="quiz">

<form onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" action="(link deleted)">

<h2>A Simple Quiz</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>About You</legend>
        <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="UserInfo" size="40">
        </div>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>The questions</legend>
<ol>
    <li>
        <p id="Q1">What does this message spell?</p>
        <div>
            <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/H.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
            <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/E.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
            <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
            <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
            <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
            <br>
            <select name="Q1">
                <option value="">Choose one from the following:</option>
                <option value="a">Happy</option>
                <option value="b">Hoppy</option>
                <option value="c">Hello</option>
                <option value="d">Cello</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p id="Q2">Which TWO of the following statements are TRUE?</p>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Q2a" id="Q2a"> <label for="Q2a">a) Another word for fingerspelling is <b>dactylogy</b></label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Q2b" id="Q2b"> <label for="Q2b">b) The first known school for the deaf was founded in 1670</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Q2c" id="Q2c"> <label for="Q2c">c) Sign languages are also used by hearing individuals</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Q2d" id="Q2d"> <label for="Q2d">d) There are only 142 sign languages that exist worldwide</label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p id="Q3">Which of these images correctly shows the sign for the letter I (India)?</p>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3a" value="a"> <label for="Q3a">a) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label> 
            <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3b" value="b"> <label for="Q3b">b) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/I.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label> 
            <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3c" value="c"> <label for="Q3c">c) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/A.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label> 
            <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3d" value="d"> <label for="Q3d">d) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/U.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p id="Q4">BANZL is the acronym for which sign language family?</p>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="Q4" size="40">
        </div>
    </li>

</ol>

<input type="hidden" name="thisScore">

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Submit your answers</legend>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> or <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>

</fieldset>




</form>
</div>


<div id="footer">  
    <p>Answers can be found at <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language">Wikipedia</a></p>
</div>

</div>




</body></html>
```

Here is what I've done in my JavaScript file:

```
var invalid = 0;

function validate(){

invalid = 0;

if (document.getElementById("UserInfo").value == ""){

        alert('Name cannot be empty!');

        invalid+=1;
        }



    if(invalid != 0){
    return false;
    }

    else {
    return true;
    }


}
```

The reason for the variable "invalid" is that I will add many if statements and use the variable for each one

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Despite the doctype, the code is not XHTML (It's not even well-formed) so I've removed the xhtml tags.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your id placement `id="UserInfo"` it should not in paragraph tag

`<p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>`

it should in input tag

`<input type="text" id="UserInfo" name="UserInfo" size="40">`

Answer (score -2):

you are returning wrong result semantically, it should be

```
if(invalid != 0){
return true;
}

else {
return false;
}
```

And `id` should be on `input` from which you are getting value not on `p`.

`<input type="text" id="UserInfo" size="40">`

find working example below with bit better approach

```js
var invalid;

function validate() {

  invalid = false;

  if (document.getElementById("UserInfo").value == "") {

    alert('Name cannot be empty!');

    invalid = true;
  }


  return !invalid;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <h1>Sign Language</h1>


  <div id="quiz">

    <form onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" action="(link deleted)">

      <h2>A Simple Quiz</h2>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>About You</legend>
        <p>What is your name?</p>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="UserInfo" name="UserInfo" size="40">
        </div>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>The questions</legend>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <p id="Q1">What does this message spell?</p>
            <div>
              <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/H.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
              <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/E.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
              <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
              <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/L.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
              <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign">
              <br>
              <select name="Q1">
                <option value="">Choose one from the following:</option>
                <option value="a">Happy</option>
                <option value="b">Hoppy</option>
                <option value="c">Hello</option>
                <option value="d">Cello</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p id="Q2">Which TWO of the following statements are TRUE?</p>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Q2a" id="Q2a"> <label for="Q2a">a) Another word for fingerspelling is <b>dactylogy</b></label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Q2b" id="Q2b"> <label for="Q2b">b) The first known school for the deaf was founded in 1670</label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Q2c" id="Q2c"> <label for="Q2c">c) Sign languages are also used by hearing individuals</label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="Q2d" id="Q2d"> <label for="Q2d">d) There are only 142 sign languages that exist worldwide</label>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p id="Q3">Which of these images correctly shows the sign for the letter I (India)?</p>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3a" value="a"> <label for="Q3a">a) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/O.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3b" value="b"> <label for="Q3b">b) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/I.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3c" value="c"> <label for="Q3c">c) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/A.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label>
              <input type="radio" name="Q3" id="Q3d" value="d"> <label for="Q3d">d) <img src="./A BSL Quiz_files/U.png" height="100" width="100" alt="A BSL sign"></label>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <p id="Q4">BANZL is the acronym for which sign language family?</p>
            <div>
              <input type="text" name="Q4" size="40">
            </div>
          </li>

        </ol>

        <input type="hidden" name="thisScore">

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit your answers</legend>

        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"> or <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </div>

      </fieldset>




    </form>
  </div>


  <div id="footer">
    <p>Answers can be found at <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_language">Wikipedia</a></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: plz look at code again, OP is returning `false` even if value is empty which is clearly invalid